# Construct path with help of Variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am doing a page where directory structure like this

/2017/05/14/

I am using variable to get current year, month and day after I am defining  BASE URL in head section which is working without errors. But when I am trying to assign these path values to another variable it is printing variable names instead Value.

I need to define BASE_URL or BASE_PATH with the help of $required_year, $required_month, $required_day and need to include some files depending on this BASE_URL

I hope that I have explained what I want.

1. Construct BASE_URL with help of variable $required_year and so on
2. include some php files depending on the constructed BASE_URL

   ```
   <?php
   $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   $host_upper = strtoupper($host);
   $path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

   $required_year = $_GET['Year'];
   $required_month = $_GET['Month'];
   $required_day = $_GET['Day'];

   define('BASE_URL', '"http://" . $host .  "/" . $required_year . "/" . $required_month . "/" . $required_day . "/"');
   define('BASE_PATH', '/echo $required_year/echo $required_month/echo $required_day . "/"');

   $wowURL = '"http://" . $host .  "/" . $required_year . "/" . $required_month . "/" . $required_day . "/"';

   ?>
   <html>
   <head>


   <base href="http://basharatnews.localhost/<?php echo $required_year ?>/<?php echo $required_month ?>/<?php echo $required_day ?>/"/>
   </head>

   <?php


   echo 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

   echo $wowURL;
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Instead of making some crazy directory structure, you should use a routing library. For example: [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannnot make variable in the `''`, which will maek the variable name as string, not it's value.

```
'"http://" . $host .  "/" . $required_year . "/" . $required_month . "/" . $required_day . "/"'
```

should be

```
"http://" . $host .  "/" . $required_year . "/" . $required_month . "/" . $required_day . "/"
```